# Error in JavaScript on Canvas(HTML5)- can't figure it out

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, pixel

I have JavaScript code in my site.
The code is using 2 identical photos-same size, same resolution - only different colors.
First photo is black and white photo - this is what the canvas presents.
Second photo is the same only with the original colors.
I have a button that triggers JS code - which generally removes a pixel from the black and white -and paints color pixel on the canvas. At first I used Math.random for the pixel locations.
And than I decided to use it by order. No matter where it starts or begging.. as long it will go
in this order `(x,y)..(x+1,y)..` until maximum x.. and than `(x,y+1)..` until maximum x.. and so on until all the black and white photo "transformed" into the colorful photo..
for some reason I just cant make it happen.. i tried a lot of techniques..
here is demo for global understanding: 
demo is working sorry - they deactivated my free host :\ hope you still understand..

here is the original code- i just changed the last function : `**removeDrawRandomPixel**` ..it's just playing the function there and it should be fixed..

```
///////////////////////global variables///////////////////
var gray_url="bwcat.jpg"; //black and white image URI
var regular_url="cat.jpg"; //regular image URI
var n=100; //number of pixels changed per click
/////////////////////////////////////

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var c=new EditableCanvas(document.getElementById('cnvs'));
    grayScaleImage=new Image();
    grayScaleImage.src=gray_url;
    grayScaleImage.onload=function()
    {
        c.drawImage(this);
    }
    regularImage=new Image();
    regularImage.src=regular_url;
    regularImage.onload=function()
    {
        var p=getPixelArray(this);
        btn.onclick=function(){
                for(var i=1;i<=n&&p.length>0;i++){
                removeDrawRandomPixel(p,c);
                }
            }
    }
},false);   

//create a Pixel object
function ImagePixel(x,y,r,g,b,a)
{
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.r=r;
    this.g=g;
    this.b=b;
    this.a=a;
}

//object that allows custom methods
function EditableCanvas(canvas)
{
    this.canvas=canvas;
    this.context=canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.width=canvas.width;
    this.height=canvas.height;
    this.pixelImage=this.context.createImageData(1,1);
    //draw an entire picture and adjust the canvas for it
    this.drawImage=function(image)
    {
        this.width=image.width;
        this.height=image.height;
        this.canvas.height=image.height;
        this.canvas.width=image.width;
        this.context.drawImage(image,0,0);
    }
    //draw a single pixel, ImagePixel pixel
    this.drawPixel=function(pixel)
    {
        this.pixelImage.data[0]=pixel.r;
        this.pixelImage.data[1]=pixel.g;
        this.pixelImage.data[2]=pixel.b;
        this.pixelImage.data[3]=pixel.a;
        this.context.putImageData(this.pixelImage,pixel.x,pixel.y);//,pixel.x,pixel.y);
    }
}
//the function returns an ordered array of Pixel pixels of the image at `src`.
function getPixelArray(img)
{
    var pixelArray=[];
    var cnvs=document.createElement('canvas');
    cnvs.width=img.width;
    cnvs.height=img.width;
    var context=cnvs.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img,0,0);
    var originalData = context.getImageData(0,0,img.width,img.height).data;
    for(var i=0,pixelId=0,px;i<originalData.length;i+=4)
    {
        px=new ImagePixel(pixelId%img.width,Math.floor(pixelId/img.width),originalData[i],originalData[i+1],originalData[i+2],originalData[i+3]);
        pixelArray.push(px);
        pixelId++;
    }
    return pixelArray;
}

//the function remove a random pixel from pixelArray and draws it on editableCnvs
function removeDrawRandomPixel(pixelArray,editableCnvs)
{
    var place=Math.floor(Math.random()*pixelArray.length);
    var px=pixelArray.splice(place,1)[0];
    editableCnvs.drawPixel(px);
}
```

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>canvas rules</title>
        <script src="pixel.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="cnvs">
        oh goddmamit no support
        </canvas>
        <button id="btn">click to convert</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried playing the last function.. because i know the answer is in the function,how to choose the pixels..

Answer (score 0):

This is untested however this is what I would change the `removeDrawRandomPixel` function to. You are grabbing a random point in the array currently and passing it, so it could be starting on the blue component of one pixel and ending on the g component of another pixel.

```
//the function remove a random pixel from pixelArray and draws it on editableCnvs
function removeDrawRandomPixel(pixelArray,editableCnvs)
{
    // width and height need to be the width and height of the canvas.

    var width = canvas.width,
        height = canvas.height,
        x = Math.floor(Math.random()*width),
        y = Math.floo(Math.random()*height);

    var px = (y * width + x) * 4;
    editableCnvs.drawPixel(px);
}
```

Comment: in the way you describe it,i might draw again on the same point.using array and splice command is the most effective way.

Comment: i need a way to draw from the (0,0) point to the last point..it should be easy, the function already give you a array of pixels of the all img, i jut cant understand why it wont work..

Comment: @user3770900 I explained why it wont work..  you aren't grabbing the components, but just a single index from the array.

Comment: @user3770900 check this article out for a good explanation http://beej.us/blog/data/html5s-canvas-2-pixel/ without live code such as a fiddle can't really help much more than this.

Comment: still dont get it,the math random returns a number,so if i will just place another number who's not random.it will work right?i mean :var place=Math.floor((x)*pixelArray.length); and than just x+=1..at the end of the method?